# How can I see more battery info when using Gnome shell?

Tags: gnome, battery

I've been using Gnome Shell on Ubuntu and I've been fairly satisfied.  One thing that I really wish was different though is the battery icon.  I can't tell by glancing at it what my battery status is at all!

*Is there are way to add the battery charge percent or the estimated battery time to the icon?*

Comment: when I answered it said GNOME3, not GNOME Shell.

Comment: I figured as much.  I'm sorry if I sounded rude!  Thanks for taking the time to read the question.  This has been annoying me and I don't know why there isn't an easy way to do this.  It's like the gnome devs don't care about knowing how much battery they have left at a glance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at these three extensions, which may be what you are looking for!

- [Battery - remaining time and percentage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/230/battery-remaining-time/)
- [Battery Power Statistics Shortcut](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/175/battery-power-statistics-shortcut/)
- [Battery Percentage Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/23/battery-percentage-indicator/)

Answer (score 6):

Left click on the icon and click on the indicator and click **Show Time in Menu Bar**, if you are using Unity. If you are using GNOME Shell, then I don't think you can do anything about that (without an extension).

You can install [screenlets](http://packages.ubuntu.com/screenlets) [image: Install screenlets], which has a screenlet that can show you some more battery info on your desktop. You will probably need to install the battery monitor screenlet as well.

Comment: It's fairly easy to do in Unity as you mention but I haven't found any way to do it easily in gnome shell.  I'm open to using an extension but I haven't found any.  Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: @Dason: honestly I don't know of any extensions, I think you would have to write one.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I was hoping there would be an easy way to do this.  For the moment I've changed my icon theme because the Ubuntu-mono-dark icon theme (while being relatively nice looking) made the battery icon far too small which made it unusable to tell anything about my battery status.  The gnome theme seems to help a little bit and I can tell a little bit more about my battery but I'm still hoping for something that will tell me a percent or a time to discharge.

Comment: I've accepted your answer for the time being due to the addition of  screenlets.  I don't want to go that route (screenlets has always caused me trouble) but it would partially solve the issue.  I really do want a better way to view my battery status that is always visible though.

Answer (score 4):

run in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true
```

Comment: Was that available in 11.10?

Answer (score 1):

You also can install `acpid` :

```
sudo apt-get install acpid
```

and run in a terminal :

```
acpi -V
```

OR the short version :

```
acpi -i
```

This will show you usefull informations : 
[image: acpid package informations using -V option]

Answer (score 1):

For detailed info look no more.

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Comment: My question was specific to 11.10 so I have no way to test this answer anymore.  But really it was about getting the information in the icon or the status bar directly so although I appreciate the answer it doesn't seem to get at the original question.

Comment: See, people search this answer on Google *without* a specific version in mind, so it would be best if you could remove a version information from the question, and accept [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/874486/135652) because it truly answers the question in a recent version of Gnome.

Comment: Moreover, Ubuntu 11.10 reached EOL in 2013. [That's almost four years ago.](http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2013/05/10/ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-end-of-life-reached-on-may-9-2013/) Very unluckily anyone visiting this page still use 11.10.

Comment: @dason: There! everyone happy: your original Q edited and upvoted: +1 for you, and +1 for above answer...  Good enough?  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby Not particularly. I have no interest in maintaining the question beyond its original intent and the answer didn't get at the actual question of putting the information into the status bar.

Comment: @Dason if you have no interest would you please make it [a community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)? this way it could be still maintained by other interested parties

Comment: @sanmai why? You can still post answers, if you like. And you can still suggest edits. I don't really see why making a 4-year-old question which already has answers dealing with *that version* CW.

Comment: @terdon I have no problem with this question whatsoever; but it feels like the author was offended by where it's all going; if he or she could be freed from owning this question...

Comment: @sanmai making it CW won't help there. The question will still "belong" to the OP, they just stop getting rep from any upvotes to it and it only takes 100 rep to edit. But edits can be proposed to a non-CW question. So if you feel it's really worth editing, you can do so. As you can see, the version has already been removed. I don't see why CW would help any now.

Comment: @terdon and sanmai I guess my opinion is just that there were answers that worked for the version I asked about.  Just because somebody new came along with an answer that *didn't even answer the original question* I don't see why we should be changing this.  If there is enough interest a new more general question should be asked in my opinion.

Comment: @Dason there's little point in repeating the same question for newer versions. On the other hand, there's absolutely no reason for you to change your accept vote give than what you accepted had worked for the version you had asked about. If someone wants to add an answer for a newer version, that's great too and the information will be here.